# Groovy By default in Map Numeric values considered as Big decimal

Tags: groovy

I have created a Map in groovy:

```
def measureMap = [:]
measureMap.put('engine.temperature', 70.0)
measureMap.put('fuel.level', 71.0)
```

The values for this map considered as Bigdecimal.

Is there any reason for this.

Why I am asking this i know the hierarchy

```
java.lang.Object
java.lang.Number
java.math.BigDecimal
```

so I thought by default it should consider it as double/float .

Comment: IMHO a very good decision the creators of Groovy made there.  Opt for
accuracy by default and let the users choose performance, where they
need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Groovy uses `BigDecimal` for decimal numbers. This is [documented](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_decimal_literals):

> Conveniently for exact decimal number calculations, Groovy choses java.lang.BigDecimal as its decimal number type. In addition, both float and double are supported, but require an explicit type declaration, type coercion or suffix. Even if BigDecimal is the default for decimal numbers, such literals are accepted in methods or closures taking float or double as parameter types.

If you need your values to be double-typed in the map, you can add the familiar `D` or `F` suffixes for double/float literals:

```
measureMap.put('engine.temperature', 70.0d) //java.lang.Double
measureMap.put('engine.temperature', 71.0f) //java.lang.Float
```